# Detect if a sequence is exponential

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, exponential-function

We can detect that $x[n] = A^n$ is exponential since the second finite difference of its log is zero everywhere. E.g.

```
x = 2**np.arange(10)
assert np.allclose(np.diff(np.log(x), 2), 0)
```

Log makes it linear, `diff` makes it a constant, second `diff` makes it zero.

Is there such a definitive approach for the case of $x[n] = A^n + B$, where $n_0\leq n < n_1$, and we don't know $n_0$ or $n_1$? i.e. we don't actually know which $x_i$ maps to which $n$ (but we do know the length, $n_1 - n_0$)

---

**An attempt**

If $x = A^t + B$, then $d = \log(x)' = \log(A) A^t / x$, and $d\cdot x$ is exponential. But it's only approximate if the differentiator is a finite difference:

```
x = 2**np.arange(10) + 100
d = np.diff(np.log(x))
out = np.diff(np.log(d * x[1:]), 2)
print(np.abs(out).max())
```

```
>>> 0.0143
```

There are recursive / optimization methods not just to detect exponential but find $A$ and $B$ exactly, but I seek a closed form solution as with the case of $x[n]=A^n$.

Comment: What values of $n$ are you given a $x[n]$? If you have $x[0]$, then you can just subtract $B:=x[0]-1$ from all the rest of the terms and see if the rest is exponential. Anyway, if $\Delta$ is the forward difference operator so $\Delta x[n]:=x[n+1]-x[n]$ then $x[n]$ is of the form $A^n+B$ iff $\Delta x[n]/\Delta x[0]$ is exponential (same base, $A$).

Comment: @runway44 I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a set of point $(t_n,x_n)$ that you suspect has the correlation:
$$x=A^t+B$$
then for example if $t_{n+1}-t_n=1$:
$$x_{n+1}=A^{t_n+1}+B$$
$$x_n=A^{t_n}+B$$
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=A^{t_n}\left(A-1\right)$$

---

Another way would be to say:
$$x=A^t+B$$
as your function and for each point:
$$x_n\sim A^{t_n}+B$$
then use the least squares method, that is to say minimise:
$$S=\sum r_i^2$$
$$r_i=x(t_n)-x_n$$
This will just leave you with two unknowns $A,B$ and two simultaneous equations given by:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial A}=0\\
\frac{\partial S}{\partial B}=0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't seek an optimization approach.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon by optimising you can then analyse the residuals and see if they are within your error bounds, that will tell you if it is exponential or not

Comment: Your answer gave me the hint but it wasn't complete; if you edit in the necessary info (i.e. my answer), I'll accept

Answer (score 0):

I've overcomplicated things; `diff(diff(log(diff(x))) == 0`.

$$
x[n] - x[n-1] = A^n - A^{n-1} = A^n(1 - A) = CA^n
$$

so finite difference of a $A^n + B$ is a scaled pure exponential, which we can handle.